# DateTime weird behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime

I have created a C# WinForms application.

On my computer the following works:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("13/05/2012", "dd/mm/yyyy",  null)
```

but this doesn't:

```
DateTime.Parse("13/05/2012")
```

On my client's computers it's reversed. This works:

```
DateTime.Parse("13/05/2012")
```

but this doesn't:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("13/05/2012", "dd/mm/yyyy",  null)
```

The error states:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Didn't manage to find any information on the internet about this problem. The program uses .Net Framework 4 and is a x86 application. I run Windows 8 x64, the client runs Windows 7 x64.

Does anybody have a clue as to why this occurs?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suspect a discrepancy related to the systems' CultureInfo date-time formatting, but please elaborate on what "doesn't work" means. Does it produce an error? What's the error message?

Comment: @DanJ It works for him, but it parses it as "05/13/2012" at the client's computer when using the `ParseExact` method. I agree checking on the CultureInfo.

Comment: Another reason to standardize on the ISO `yyyy-MM-dd` format.  =)

Comment: @Vlad: All of your "mm" should be changed to "MM"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you are getting different behaviour on different computers is because they are running with different cultures. Try running this line of code on both computers to see if it outputs something different: [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/Nkv0c)

```
System.Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Output (example):

```
en-US
```

The culture specifies many things, one of which is the date separator. If you want consistent behaviour for all users, try specifying a culture: [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/12XWu)

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // or whatever you prefer
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("13/05/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", cultureInfo);
```

The above code assumes you have these using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: `mm` is minutes, not months, you are looking for `MM`. As your example shows.

Answer (score 11):

Be careful; in [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4), the `mm` specifier represents “minutes”, not “months”. You need to use `MM` for months.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("13/05/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```